# Float left hides background color?

Tags: css

having trouble with `float:left`, I aim to hover over the navigation bar without the gap to the left side, I can fix this by using `float:left` but once I add `float:left` into my `#topnav ul li a` it seems to remove the background color? here is my current css:

```
body {background-color:#CDCDCD;}
h1 {font-family:arial, Geneva, sans-serif;}
h2 {font-family:arial, Geneva, sans-serif;}
li {list-style:none;}
a:link { text-decoration:none;  }
#container {width:900px; margin:0px auto; background-color:#FFFFFF; border:1px solid grey;
#top  { background-color:#000000; width:100%; padding:10px 0; overflow:hidden; }
#logo { margin:0 0 0 10px; float:left; }
#social-media   {float:right; margin:15px 0px 0px 0px;  }
#social-media p {color:#ffffff; margin: 0px 0px 0px 25px; }
#social-media img { width:24px; height:24px; margin:0px 5px 0px 0px;   }
#social-media ul li { display:inline; }
#topnav { background-color:#333333; clear:both; width:100%; }
#topnav ul { margin:0px; background-color:#333333; }
#topnav ul li { display:inline; }
#topnav ul li a { padding:10px 20px; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;   display:inline-block; }
#topnav  a:link { color:#ffffff; }
#topnav  a:visited { color:#ffffff; }
#topnav  a:active { color:#ffffff;  }
#topnav  a:hover { color:#ffffff; background-color:#770000; }
#topnav  a:focus { color:#ffffff; }
#footer { width:100%; background-color:#333333; float:left; }
#footer p { text-align:center; color:#ffffff; font-size:12px; }
#footer a:link {color:white;}
```

Comment: maybe a `overflow:auto` on the parent element of the ones you are floating

Comment: Your #container selector is missing a close brace for a start. But it would probably help if you could provide some example markup to go with the CSS.

Comment: Also it looks like aurel is correct. Adding `overflow:auto` to `#topnav ul` seems to bring back the background color.